# SQL divide values in column B by distinct values dependent on entries in column A

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given columns A and B:

```
A B

Small     3

Med       4

Med       1

Large     2

Small     1
```

Let's say I have numerical values X, Y, and Z. I want to create a new column that outputs the quotients of values of column B and X only if the entry in the same row in column A is "Small". If column A has "Med", we divide by Y and if it has "Large", we divide by Z. It would continue to check this row by row. For example, in the first row of column B, we have '3', then on the same row in column A, we have 'Small', so we would output 3/X. So the expected column, let's call it C, would be:

```
C

3/X

4/Y

1/Y

2/Z

1/X
```

How would I output C using SQL?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Particular at this part "if the entry in column A is "Small" and is on the same row as the value of column".  I don't quite understand the last part (...and is on the same row as the value of column). Also, it easier for people to help you if you provide a sample of you entire dataset with columns X, Y and Z included.

Comment: Where will values for x, y, z come from? Will there be numbers used or do you really want literal characters x, y, z?

Answer (score 0):

You can use msaccess `switch` then `concatenate` your desired results

```
select  
    Switch (
        ColumnA='Small', columnB & '/'& 'X',
        ColumnA='Med', columnB & '/'& 'Y',
        ColumnA='Large', columnB & '/'& 'Z'
    )
from tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide ColumnA by a value returned from Switch() function. Use Switch because it is simpler than nested IIf(). Of course, this assumes actual numbers will be in place of x, y, z and therefore don't enclose in apostrophes or quotes.

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB,
    ColumnB / Switch(
        ColumnA="Small", x,
        ColumnA="Med", y,
        ColumnA="Large", z
    ) AS Qt
FROM table;
```