# SQL Updated question conditional division

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given columns A and B from Table1:

```
A B

Small     3

Med       4

Med       1

Large     2

Small     1
```

Given columns S, M, L from Table2:

```
S M L

5     5     3

8     2     1

4     6     5

2     2     8
```

I want to create a new column in Table1 that outputs the quotients of values of column B and Avg(Table2.S) only if the entry in the same row in column A of is 'Small'. If column A has 'Med', we divide by Avg(Table2.M) and if it has 'Large', we divide by Avg(Table2.L). It would continue to check this row by row. For example, in the first row of column B, we have '3', and on the same row in column A, we have 'Small', so we would output 0.6316 (3/Avg(Table2.S)). So the expected column, let's call it C, would be:

```
C

0.6316

1.0667

0.2667

0.4076

0.2105
```

How would I output C using MS Access SQL? I tried

```
Select
Switch(Table1.A ='Small', Table1.B/Avg(Table2.S),
Table1.A ='Med', Table1.B/Avg(Table2.M),
Table1.A ='Large', Table1.B/Avg(Table2.L))
From Table1, Table2
```

but I usually get an error that says my query doesn't include the specified expression as an aggregate function.

Comment: What's the question? `AVG()` is an aggregate function, which requires a `GROUP BY`. Your code doesn't have one.

Comment: I added a Group By Table1.A, but the same error pops up. What would be an appropriate group by?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL divide values in column B by distinct values dependent on entries in column A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061046/sql-divide-values-in-column-b-by-distinct-values-dependent-on-entries-in-column)

Comment: Any reason why you're asking the same questions twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061046/sql-divide-values-in-column-b-by-distinct-values-dependent-on-entries-in-column

Comment: I still encountered some errors, so I decided to provide more detail with what I'm working with in hopes that I could pinpoint what I need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this

```
select A,B,switch(A="Small",x.avg_s,A="Med",avg_m,A="Large",avg_l) as avg_vals,B/switch(A="Small",x.avg_s,A="Med",avg_m,A="Large",avg_l)
  from table1 y, 
          (select avg(S) as avg_s,avg(M) as avg_m,avg(L) as avg_l 
             from table2
          )x
```

The output is [image]